# C# Tracing truncate long messages

Tags: c#

In C# I've enabled tracing and a net tracing source.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net"
        type="TraceTest.StringWriterTraceListener, TraceTest"
        initializeData="myfile.log"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4" />    
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

But longer messages get truncated (long like 12Kb/30 lines, not long like 1GB!) so I end up in a situation where only part of web reqiest headers are logged.

How to fix that?

Or do you know a book or some resource that explains .Net tracing and debugging in great detail?

log example:

```
            System.Net Information: 0 : [1204] Connection#63291458 - Received headers
        {
        Transfer-Encoding: chunked
        Connection: keep-alive
        Keep-Alive: timeout=10
        Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
        Date: Mon, 04 Jul 2016 17:50:33 GMT
        Set-Cookie: uid=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0,uid=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/,uid=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=.zamunda.net,pass=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0,pass=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/,pass=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=.zamunda.net,bitbucketz=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0,bitbucketz=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/,bitbucketz=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=.zamunda.net,cats=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0,cats=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/,cats=deleted;
expires=...}.
```

This is one message, somehow `Write` method on the `TraceListener` is called whit that single message as parameter that is being truncated (the "...}." at the end)

Also cookies are terribly written and are almost unparsable, but I can live with that...

Yeah, sadly enough apart from tampering with System.dlls or using some odd and complex type inheritance there is not much to be done.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what `maxdatasize` is for? 1024 seems a little low.

Comment: Thought so, tried it with 32768 and 20000, but obviously it's not for that or there is some other attribute that must be set, but I'm unable to find a list of attributes. Strange enough way larger webpages html is being outputed as hex without being truncated, but I haven't tested if this happends in one message.

Comment: If you're only interested in webrequests why don't you use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: I've put great effort to hack around config limitation of this, exactly not to use fiddler core API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll not get the extra data.

Your typical example is coming from an private method called `ParseResponseData` which calls this:

```
Logging.PrintInfo(Logging.Web, this, SR.GetString("net_log_received_headers", new object[]
    {
        this.m_ResponseData.m_ResponseHeaders.ToString(true)
    }));
```

The internal sealed static class `SR` with method `GetString` is the culprit here. The *net_log_received_headers* resource string is *Received headers {{{0}}}.*. ILSpy reveals this code:

```
public static string GetString(string name, params object[] args)
{
    SR sR = SR.GetLoader();
    if (sR == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    string @string = sR.resources.GetString(name, SR.Culture);
    if (args != null && args.Length != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            string text = args[i] as string;
            if (text != null && text.Length > 1024)
            {
                args[i] = text.Substring(0, 1021) + "...";
            }
        }
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, @string, args);
    }
    return @string;
}
```

You notice this piece:

```
if (text != null && text.Length > 1024)
{
    args[i] = text.Substring(0, 1021) + "...";
}
```

What ever you throw at it, it will rewrite the arguments to limit its length to 1024 characters.

As the ResponseHeaders collection write all its name/values to a single string, once it is handed to `SR.GetString` all that effort and memory is wasted.

When `SR.GetString` is involved in the logging, you'll risk having your data truncated. The only way to know where that happens is by inspecting the assembly  or the [.Net Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_Connection.cs,2557)

The `maxdatasize` setting in the config is used when the `Dump` method of the internal `Logging` class is called. However, you'll not have to guess if the data is truncated because it will tell you that in the log file:

```
int maxDumpSizeSetting = Logging.GetMaxDumpSizeSetting(traceSource);
if (length > maxDumpSizeSetting)
{
    Logging.PrintLine(traceSource, TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, string.Concat(new string[]
    {
        "(printing ",
        maxDumpSizeSetting.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
        " out of ",
        length.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
        ")"
    }));
    length = maxDumpSizeSetting;
}
```